# Displaying realtime socket io response on website

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, web-deployment

I am working on a personal project that will allow me to get information about my computer (current battery level, current CPU usage, etc) and display it on a simple website in real time. To accomplish this I developed a client program that would run my computer, and a server (running on node.js) to receive the data from the client. To do so I have implemented socket io to collect and demand data from the client.

example:

server side:

```
socket.emit("GET_DATA");
```

client side:

```
socket.on("GET_DATA", function(){
    // Collect data from client machine
    // ...
    // pass data back to server
    socket.emit("PASS_DATA_TO_SERVER", collectedData);
});
```

server side:

```
socket.on("PASS_DATA_TO_SERVER", function(data){
    // data has been collected!! Stored in the data JSON object, 
    // however limited to the scope of this function... 
    // (thats a problem)
});
```

The problem I now face is displaying the data the server just received on my website (hosted on the same server and same node js program that is running the socket io component).

Here is a visual display of the working components of the system:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPdbO.jpg)

I am a first year student, and do not have a lot of programming practices under my belt yet. If anyone is able to give me a point in the right direction of what to search for, or point out a major flaw in my logic this would be extremely helpful.

If their is any additional information about the project that is needed, I am more then willing to provide it.

---

Order of the transaction:

1. The user will connect to the website hosted on the node js server
   example: http://example_url.com/ ---> website will be displayed
2. Once the user has made a connection to the website, the user will be able to request data from the computer running the client side program. 

   example:

   - user connects to site (step 1 ^)
   - user clicks magic button
   - server emits event to machine running the client application to get data
   - machine running client application returns data back to the server
   - server sends data to the webpage, displaying it to the user.

      Repeat step 1 through 2, until user exits the site (closes tab, exits browser)

note: The client who is viewing the webpage and the client who is providing the data are two different machines.

Comment: The description of how you want to display the data is not clear.  You will have to describe the exact steps that a user takes in order to see this data.  Typically a user would go to a specific URL on your server and get a web page back and see data in that web page.  Is that what you're trying to do?  If so, then you either have to store the battery/CPU data on the server so you can put it in a future web page for that user or you have to insert the data directly into the web page using Javascript in the browser (since the data came from the user anyway).

Comment: I added in the order of transactions that describe the process in which the system should work. As I stated above though, I have no background doing something like, so if the way I am going about this is complete garbage let me know :) @jfriend00

Comment: also, the client that connects to the website component of the server does not connect to the socket io component. I had thought about doing this, but wasn't sure if was a good idea or not as the sockets main purpose is to only collect data from the client running the desktop application.

Comment: I suggest that the web client connect to socket.io too. It would make things easier. The sockets main purpose is the real-time communication which is your case. Wouldn't you like to monitor data and push them to your web client without any magic button action? Just thinking...

Comment: [tag:real-time] has a specific meaning in computing, and this isn't it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this:

server.js

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const interval = 1000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

setInterval( function() {
  io.emit("get data");
}, interval);

io.on('connect', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected from: ' + socket.handshake.address);
  socket.on('pass data to server', function(info){
    io.emit('send data to anybody', info);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

client.js

```
'use strict';
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
var info = {};

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected to server');
});

socket.on('get data', function() {
  info.battery = Math.random().toFixed(4);
  info.cpu = Math.random().toFixed(4);
  info.memory = Math.random().toFixed(4); 
  console.log('battery: ' + info.battery + ', CPU: ' + info.cpu + ', memory: ' + info.memory);
  socket.emit('pass data to server', info);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing Socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='socket'>not connected</h1>
    <p id='battery'> </p>
    <p id='cpu'> </p>
    <p id='memory'> </p>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();

      socket.on('connect', function(){
        document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML = 'connected to the server';
      });

      socket.on('send data to anybody', function(info){
        document.getElementById('battery').innerHTML = 'Battery: ' + (info.battery*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        document.getElementById('cpu').innerHTML = 'CPU: ' + (info.cpu*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
        document.getElementById('memory').innerHTML = 'Memory: ' + (info.memory*100).toFixed(2) + '%';
      });

      socket.on('disconnected',function(){
        document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML = 'disconnected';
      });        

    </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```